# How do I bind the super key (windows key) to the applications menu in the lxde desktop environment?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, lxde

I've read the other answers on this site and none of them help!

What I've tried:

- binding the Super_L key
- binding the Super_R key (which does not exist on my keyboard anyway)
- binding "Win"
- binding "Win-W"
- binding "Super"
  etc.

Is there a new way to do it now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that after editing `lxde-rc.xml` you have to run `openbox-lxde --reconfigure` in order to see the change.