# Is the superkey ever used in Ubuntu by default?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am using Thinkpad T400. My left Alt key has stopped working. The super key (with Windows logo) is just left next to it.

I was wondering if it has been used by Ubuntu (16.04 and  any future LTS edition) or any common application? 
I am using LXDE, and I haven't used the super key yet.

If not, I would like to map the super key to left Alt key, and use the super key as if it were the left Alt key.

Instead of super key, what other key near the left Alt key may I use to substitute the left Alt key?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Yes, if using Unity the super key pulls up the menu, with various shortcuts assigned to it.  Even in my MATE desktop (16.04) the super key starts the menu dialog.  I suspect other DE's use it too .  *I would expect gnome to use it too, but don't have a gnome system running to try*

Comment: Thanks. I am using LXDE, and I haven't used the super key yet.  If not super key, what other key may I use to substitute the left Alt key?

Comment: I believe that LXDE and XFCE4 do not use the super key by default.  I use XFCE4 and it does not have it set.

Comment: @Terrance  Thanks. Do you know how to substitute the left Alt key with the super key ? I am still trying to figure it out, by `xmodmap`.

Comment: Maybe this one might help:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86936/111521

Comment: A potential duplicate with no up-votes and an answer with no up-votes that may be of interest (but not sufficient for closing this question I think): https://askubuntu.com/questions/861855/how-do-i-bind-the-super-key-windows-key-to-the-applications-menu-in-the-lxde-d?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Terrance Thanks. I run a command using `xmodmap`, and now the super key sometimes work like Alt_L but sometimes not. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026246/why-doesnt-my-substitution-of-the-super-key-for-the-alt-l-key-not-work-in-all-t

Answer (score 1):

Some WMs or DEs do use the Meta key (as it is generally mapped on recent Linux systems) for certain actions as a non-modifier key such as for opening Dash on Ubuntu Unity. It is also often mapped to certain behavior such as window snapping to resize a window to a certain part of the screen. If you use none of this behavior and would derive more utility from it being mapped to left alt, xmodmap is probably the easiest way to go:

Run `xev` to get the keycode for your meta/super key, then insert it in the format approximately shown below:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 0x133 = Alt_L'
```

Comment: Thanks. I run a similar command using `xmodmap`, but the super key doesn't work like Alt_L all the time. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026246/why-doesnt-my-substitution-of-the-super-key-for-the-alt-l-key-not-work-in-all-t