# Why doesn't my substitution of the super key for the Alt_L key not work in all the cases?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

On Thinkpad T400, my left Alt key has stopped working. Since [I have never used the super key in LXDE in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026238/is-the-superkey-ever-used-in-ubuntu-by-default?noredirect=1#comment1667743_1026238), I did the following to modify the super key as if it were the left Alt key.

First I need to find out the relevant information about the two keys by running  `xev`.

When I press the left Alt key, `xev` doesn't output anything. 
I can only deduce the information about the left Alt key from the right Alt key. When I press the right Alt key,

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xb2, subw 0x0, time 942676, (262,45), root:(264,68),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xb2, subw 0x0, time 942812, (262,45), root:(264,68),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I press the super key,

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xb2, subw 0x0, time 943386, (262,45), root:(264,68),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xb2, subw 0x0, time 943498, (262,45), root:(264,68),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Then in a bash shell, after I run

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Alt_L"
```

the super key sometimes works as left Alt key, e.g.

- when I switch to the first tab of firefox by `Alt+1` (via `super+1`).

But the super key sometimes doesn't work as left Alt key, e.g.

- when I switch to the first tab of `lxterminal` by `Alt+1` (via `super+1`),
- when I want to switch between the windows of different applications by `Alt+tab` via `super+tab` (strangely, `Alt_R + tab` doesn't work either, although `Alt_L + tab` worked when the left Alt key worked before).
- when I work in Emacs, which requires to use Alt key a lot,
- When I want to invoke a program, by firstly `Alt + F2` via `super + F2`
- When I want to close the window of a program, by `Alt + F4` via `super + F4`

I was wondering why
the super key doesn't work as the left Alt key in all the cases?

I followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86933/swap-alt-and-super/86936#86936 and https://askubuntu.com/a/296437/1471, but I might have missed something, and I also notice that they are trying to swap two working keys, instead of substitute one nonworking key with a working key.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you also need to execute `remove Mod1 = Alt_L` and `add Mod1 = Super_L`

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a little what they mean?